# No main class found?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I've got to create a simple chat for my university, and when I try to run it on NetBeans it says: "No main classes found". I don't understand, I believe I do have a main class, so can anyone tell me where is the problem? Here is the code:

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.net.*;

public class server {
    private static ServerSocket socketservidor = null;
    private static Socket socketcliente = null;
    private static final int maxclientes = 4;
    private static final clienteThread[] hilos = new clienteThread[maxclientes];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int puerto = 2222;
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("CONEXION REALIZADA CORRECTAMENTE \n"
                    + "CHAT INICIADO CORRECTAMENTE \n" + "NUM. PUERTO="
                    + puerto);
        } else {
            puerto = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
        }

        try {
            socketservidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                socketcliente = socketservidor.accept();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < maxclientes; i++) {
                    if (hilos[i] == null) {
                        (hilos[i] = new clienteThread(socketcliente, hilos))
                                .start();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == maxclientes) {
                    PrintStream oc = new PrintStream(
                            socketcliente.getOutputStream());
                    oc.println("Servidor ocupado. Vuelve a intentar más tarde");
                    oc.close();
                    socketcliente.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

class clienteThread extends Thread {

    private PrintStream salida = null;
    private DataInputStream entrada = null;
    private int maxclientes;
    private final clienteThread[] threads;
    private Socket socketcliente = null;

    public clienteThread(Socket socketcliente, clienteThread[] threads) {
        this.socketcliente = socketcliente;
        this.threads = threads;
        maxclientes = threads.length;
    }

    public void run() {
        int maxclientes = this.maxclientes;
        clienteThread[] threads = this.threads;

        try {
            entrada = new DataInputStream(socketcliente.getInputStream());
            salida = new PrintStream(socketcliente.getOutputStream());
            salida.println("Solo nos falta saber tu nombre para empezar:");
            String nombre = entrada.readLine().trim();
            salida.println("Bienvenido a nuestro chat " + nombre + "\n"
                    + "Ya puedes chatear con otros usuarios!" + "\n"
                    + " teclea /salir para abandonar chat");
            for (int i = 0; i < maxclientes; i++) {
                if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
                    threads[i].salida.println("***" + nombre
                            + " se ha conectado!!!***");
                }
            }
            while (true) {
                String linea = entrada.readLine();
                if (linea.startsWith("/salir")) {
                    break;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < maxclientes; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
                        threads[i].salida.println(">>" + nombre + ":" + linea);
                    }
                    if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
                        threads[i].salida.println("YO:" + linea);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < maxclientes; i++) {
                if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
                    threads[i].salida.println("***" + nombre
                            + " se ha desconectado***");
                }
            }
            salida.println("***Te has desconectado del chat***");

            for (int i = 0; i < maxclientes; i++) {
                if (threads[i] == this) {
                    threads[i] = null;
                }
            }
            entrada.close();
            salida.close();
            socketcliente.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried reproducing the problem with a simpler programme?

Comment: How do you run it? And have you built your project?

Comment: The IDE might not be auto-compiling the sources. This could be a reason for your error.

Comment: I don't think that should even compile.  You have two classes in the same file, which isn't allowed in Java.

Comment: Are you sure Netbeans knows which class is your main class? It should ask, but if there is a problem during compilation, there will be no classes at all.

Comment: @JeremyP Actually it is allowed with the condition that only one is public; or you could have inner static classes that can be public.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name must be the same as your java class name. For example, if class name is "sever", then file should be called server.java. I could lunched it with eclipse.

Comment: `server` is a valid (though not customary) class name.

Comment: Class names do not have to start with a capital letter, it is just prefferred style.

Comment: if your JAVA_HOME is set properly, then you should be able to lunch from comand line "javac server.java" After you navigated to directory with your java file.

This is wat I get in the console, after compiling this file:

"server.java:40: warning: unmappable character for encoding Cp1257

                    oc.println("Servidor ocupado. Vuelve a intentar m├?s tarde");

                                                                      ^
Note: server.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

1 warning "

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Right Click on the project folder, click on properties, then select run from the menu on the left hand side. You will be able to see main class on the right now. Click on browse and then select the server class. Then when you will run the project the error will not be there and your server will start running.